# Get a representative vector from a large set, and compare it with samples.

Tags: calculus, statistics, arithmetic

We're a small team of programmers and we're triying to solve a little problem, but we think we need some advices from professional mathematicians.

We want to know if a picture of a card is an Identity Card or not, so we've implemented this algorithm (I've simplified a lot so we can be focused in the maths problems).

1.- Take a sample of a lot of Id Cards and make a color map of each one of them. This map is a 360 dimensional vector of integer values (An array of 360 elements).
2.- With the previous data, we calc one representative vector. Actually, we make this representative vector calculating the arithmetic mean for each dimension.
3.- We take the image that we want to identify, calc the color map vector and compare it with the representative vector. (We're using the Pearson correlation coefficient)
4.- If the coefficient is near 1, our image is an Id Card.

We're obtaining reasonable results, but this are our questions:

1.- Are there any method better than the arithmetic mean to construct the representative vector?
2.- Are there any method better than then Pearson correlation coefficient to compare boths vectors?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I wonder if you might also check [*Area-51*](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1691/signal-processing) for this question? Regards

Comment: I'll do it. Thank you very much.